# Using setLocation to move the JFrame around Windows, Java

Tags: java, swing, jframe, actionevent

I am trying to move a `JFrame` around in Windows using 5 buttons (North, East, South, West, and Centre) At the moment all the current code is in place and it works when using;

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    if(e.getSource()==northButton)
    {
       setLocation(500,500);
    }

} //works

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    if(e.getSource()== northButton)
    {
       setLocation(north);
    }

} //doesn't work
```

However as part of the task I need to use the Java Toolkit to `getScreenSize` width and height and using calculations to work out the boundaries of the screen and send 'north' to `setLocation()` (like above). However, using this method  it throws an error `"No suitable method found"` I'm unsure of how to fix this. The calculation code is below just for north at the moment.

```
int screenWidth = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().width;
int screenHeight = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().height;

int width = this.getWidth();
int height = this.getHeight();

int north = ((screenWidth - width)/2);
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here you are passing two parameters, X and Y:

```
setLocation(500,500);
```

Here you are passing one, but which is it?  X or Y?  If X, where's Y?:

```
int north = ((screenWidth - width)/2);
setLocation(north);
```

The compiler is telling you it doesn't have a `setLocation()` method that takes one parameter.  It wants a location in 2D space: that's an X *and* Y. Probably what you want is:

```
setLocation(north, 0);
```

Answer (score 3):

`Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize()` returns the full size of the **default** screen, it does not take into consideration things like task bars or other elements which may occupy space on the desktop which windows should avoid been placed under/over.

A better solution would be to use `Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenInsets(GraphicsConfiguration)` and `GraphicsConfiguration#getBounds`

```
public static Rectangle getScreenViewableBounds(Window window) {
    return getScreenViewableBounds((Component) window);
}

public static Rectangle getScreenViewableBounds(Component comp) {
    return getScreenViewableBounds(getGraphicsDevice(comp));
}

public static Rectangle getScreenViewableBounds(GraphicsDevice gd) {
    Rectangle bounds = new Rectangle(0, 0, 0, 0);
    if (gd == null) {
        GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
        gd = ge.getDefaultScreenDevice();
    }

    if (gd != null) {
        GraphicsConfiguration gc = gd.getDefaultConfiguration();
        bounds = gc.getBounds();

        Insets insets = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenInsets(gc);
        bounds.x += insets.left;
        bounds.y += insets.top;
        bounds.width -= (insets.left + insets.right);
        bounds.height -= (insets.top + insets.bottom);
    }

    return bounds;
}

/**
 * Attempts to locate the graphics device that the component most likely is
 * on.
 *
 * This calculates the area that the window occupies on each screen deivce and
 * returns the one which it occupies the most.
 *
 * @param comp
 * @return
 */
public static GraphicsDevice getGraphicsDevice(Component comp) {

    GraphicsDevice device = null;

    GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
    GraphicsDevice lstGDs[] = ge.getScreenDevices();

    ArrayList<GraphicsDevice> lstDevices = new ArrayList<GraphicsDevice>(lstGDs.length);

    if (comp != null && comp.isVisible()) {

        Rectangle parentBounds = comp.getBounds();

        /*
         * If the component is not a window, we need to find its location on the
         * screen...
         */
        if (!(comp instanceof Window)) {

            Point p = new Point(0, 0);

            SwingUtilities.convertPointToScreen(p, comp);
            parentBounds.setLocation(p);

        }

        for (GraphicsDevice gd : lstGDs) {

            GraphicsConfiguration gc = gd.getDefaultConfiguration();
            Rectangle screenBounds = gc.getBounds();

            if (screenBounds.intersects(parentBounds)) {

                lstDevices.add(gd);

            }

        }

        if (lstDevices.size() == 1) {

            device = lstDevices.get(0);

        } else {

            GraphicsDevice gdMost = null;
            float maxArea = 0;

            for (GraphicsDevice gd : lstDevices) {

                int width = 0;
                int height = 0;

                GraphicsConfiguration gc = gd.getDefaultConfiguration();
                Rectangle bounds = gc.getBounds();

                Rectangle2D intBounds = bounds.createIntersection(parentBounds);

                float perArea = (float) ((intBounds.getWidth() * intBounds.getHeight()) / (parentBounds.width * parentBounds.height));

                if (perArea > maxArea) {

                    maxArea = perArea;
                    gdMost = gd;

                }

            }

            if (gdMost != null) {

                device = gdMost;

            }

        }

    }

    return device;

}
```

The main issue you're having is that there is no such method as `setLocation(int)`...what would the value `int` represent any way?  x or y position?

You need to pass both the x and y position to `setLocation` in order for it to work.

```
Rectangle bounds = getScreenViewableBounds(this); // where this is a reference to your window
int x = bounds.x + ((bounds.width - getWidth()) / 2;
int y = bounds.y;

setLocation(x, y);
```

For example...

Comment: I thought this might be helpful, but getGraphicsDevice(comp) does not exist.

Comment: No, you need to write a method

Comment: @StanTowianski That's what you get for copying and pasting library code :P - Updated